# AppleScript - Expected end of line etc. But found classname (-2741)

Tags: macos, ms-word, applescript

I am new to Mac application development and our existing Mac application contains an AppleScript that handles all the Microsoft Word operations. When i build the solution via XCode in Catalina MacOS **that do not have Microsoft Word installed in it**, it is throwing a build error as "**Expected end of line etc. But found classname (-2741)**" .

The error is thrown exactly in the line of code shown below

[image: Expected End of line error]

When i build the same solution in Mojave MacOS **that has Microsoft Installed in it** then it is working fine without any build errorsand the build is getting succeeded.

Can you please suggest on how to handle the AppleScript such that the solution gets build without any errors irrespective of Microsoft Word installed or not? This is of high priority and needs to be fixed at the earliest.

Comment: The application needs to be installed on the build machine so that AppleScript can load its scripting terminology.

Comment: @red_menace So it is mandatory that Microsoft Word needs to be installed for the applescript to be built without any build errors? Is there another way of surpassing the build errors if Microsoft Word is not installed in the build machine.

Comment: You can write the AppleScript using raw typecodes ("chevron" syntax), so there's no terminology that needs to be looked up.

Comment: @CJK I am new to applescript development. So, can you please suggest on how it can be done such that the applescript terminology cannot be looked up?

Comment: You would need to look up the raw codes from somewhere.  The easiest way would probably be to develop the script on a machine that has the application installed, then move the compiled script to the development machine or use something like Script Debugger to show the chevron syntax.  You may still get the "Where is the app?" dialogs, though.